# How to implement multilayer in asp.net core web api when using repostiry pattern?

Tags: design-patterns, asp.net-core-webapi

I am very new to programming actually I have different layer in project basically I want to to perform database related operation in separate data access layer not in repository concrete class, I have searched on google to solve my problem but could not find any help to solve my problem, sorry about my weak English.

**webApi(Controller)**

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("api/account/Login")]
    public int Login(LoginViewModel model)
    {          
            var result = _accountRepository.Login(model);
            return result;         
    }
```

**Repository (in another library project)**

```
 public class AccountRepository : IAccountRepository
    {
private readonly AccountAction _AccountAction;

        public AccountRepository(AccountAction accountAction)
        {
  
            _AccountAction = accountAction;
        }
        public int Login(LoginViewModel model)
            {
               
                    var result = _AccountAction.LoginUser(model);
                    return result;
               
            }
      }
```

**Data Access layer**

```
public class AccountAction
    {
        private readonly IDBHelper _dapper;       
        public AccountAction(IDBHelper dapper)
        {
            _dapper = dapper;
        }
        
        public int LoginUser(LoginViewModel model)
        {
            var p = new DynamicParameters();
            p.Add("@pLogin", model.Email);
            p.Add("@pPassword", model.Password);
            var result = _dapper.Get<int>("[uspLoginUser]", p, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
            return result;

        }
    }
```

**DBHelper**

```
public interface IDBHelper : IDisposable  
    {
        DbConnection GetConnection();
        T Get<T>(string sp, DynamicParameters parms, CommandType commandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure);
        List<T> GetAll<T>(string sp, DynamicParameters parms, CommandType commandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure);
        int Execute(string sp, DynamicParameters parms, CommandType commandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure);
        T Insert<T>(string sp, DynamicParameters parms, CommandType commandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure);
        T Update<T>(string sp, DynamicParameters parms, CommandType commandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure);
    }
```

**Startup.cs**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllers();
            // Add functionality to inject IOptions<T>
            services.AddOptions();

            // Add our Config object so it can be injected
            services.Configure<DbConnectionString>(options => Configuration.GetSection("ConnectionStrings").Bind(options));
            services.AddScoped<IAccountRepository, AccountRepository>();
        }
```

**IN repository I am injecting AccountAction class which is in dataaccess layer class to access method of accountaction class but I got this exception**

```
System.AggregateException: 'Some services are not able to be constructed 
(Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: 
 Repostories.IAccountRepository Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: 
Repostories.AccountRepository': Unable to resolve service for type 
'DataAccess.Account.AccountAction' while attempting to activate 
'Repostories.AccountRepository'.)'
**2 Inner Exception.** InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service 
for type 'DataAccess.Account.AccountAction' while attempting to activate 'Repostories.AccountRepository'.
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: @MarkSeemann basically I don't want to write parameters and query exception in repository concrete class I want to move this logic to dataacess layer. Repository should be just to call a method which is in dataaccess layer.

Comment: What prevents you from doing that?

Comment: @MarkSeemann I have edited my code and attached a exception please look into that and share how can I resolve my issue or which design pattern I should follow which can resolve my issue thanks.

Comment: It looks as though you also need to register `AccountAction` with the DI Container.

Comment: @MarkSeemann still no luck i got this exception "Some services are not able to be constructed" this is how i have written
services.AddScoped<IAccountRepository, AccountRepository>();
            services.AddTransient <AccountAction> ();
            services.AddTransient<IDBHelper,DBHelper>();

Comment: What does the exception message say?

Comment: @MarkSeemann thank you very much for responding to my question I have resolved my problem by simply creating object in every action method to call a dataaccess layer methods, rather than injecting into DI container.

Comment: @xaify... why don't you answer your question so that others can learn from your experience.